# How do I concattinate my angular2 app javascript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, gulp

For my angular2 typescript app I concat all my js files into one app.min.js file, then System.import this file to my index.html page.

I then get a **Multiple anonymous System.register calls in the same module file** error in my console log.

I put all my Javascript files (not libraries) into app.min.js and then on my index.html page I then import the file using system.import to import that js file.

When I concat all the Javascript files into one file I do them in a certain order.

Maybe I'm missing some references or settings in my configs?

**This is my index.html page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <base href="/"></base>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!"/>
    <meta content="IE=edge, chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes"/>


    <!-- inject:css -->    
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/styles.af010955.css">    
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- Js libs -->    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/safariPolyFix.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>   

    <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            defaultJSExtensions: true,  
            typescriptOptions: {
                emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
            },          
            packages: {
                'angular2-google-maps': {
                  defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });       
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular2_google_maps.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/firebase/firebaseNew.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body id="container">

    <app></app>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
      System.import('/app/app.min.js');
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my gulp file:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('app', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/app/app.component.js', 'src/app/*.js', 'src/app/filters/*.js', 'src/app/models/**/*.js', 'src/app/components/**/*.js', 'src/app/services/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['app']);
```

**This is my tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**This is my screen grab of the error:**

[image]

**This is the source files in the browser console:**

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you require me to add any more files

Comment: Maybe my System.config on the index page is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can't concat js files by your own that are generated by the typescript compiler.

If you want to have all of them in a single file, you need to leverage the outFile property of the compiler in the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outFile": "app.js" <-------
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added your code. is the outFile app.js meant to be same as in the gulp?

Comment: My answer of this question could also help you:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app/36315060

Comment: Ok I will have a look at that link. Currently the tsconfig.json change hasnt made a difference

Comment: You could specify rhis parameter in gulp directly ;-)

Comment: For this line: var tsResult = gulp.src('app/**/*.ts') can I use an array like this: var tsResult = gulp.src(['','','']) as I have many typescript files in folders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111940/discussion-between-angularm-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Currently when I run gulp the only error I get is that it doesnt no what Firebase is?

Comment: I've just added this reference and it seems to have solved the firebase errors on gulp: /// <reference path="../firebase/firebase.d.ts" />

Comment: I still get this error though: Multiple anonymous System.register calls in the same module file. in the console log

Comment: In my index.html page I now just called the app.min.js like so: <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.min.js"></script> but in the console log I still get the same error: "Multiple anonymous System.register calls in the same module file."